# How to disable a multi-row push button for all rows except the current one in Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a form that returns multiple rows with a single push button that is displayed at the end of each row. The form allows a user to insert a new row at the end. Whilst a new row is being inserted, I do not want the users to be able to use the push button on any other row other than the current one they are inserting.

I have tried using SET_ITEM_PROPERTY and SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY to disable the other buttons however this just disables the button for all rows including the one I am inserting.

I'm still quite new to Oracle Forms so has anyone any ideas as to how I can solve this problem?

If it matters i'm using Forms 10G.

Thanks.

Comment: A simple workaround would be to write the code for the button to show a suitable alert if it's clicked on a new record.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I did and I have found a solution to the problem.

Comment: You should be able to do that with SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY but you would have store de record number of your current row, and then go through all the records of the block and disable the button one by one except for the one that's in the row you stored previously.